# How can I parse urls from csv in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is my code. This code works fine for the given single url. I would like to parse urls from CSV. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Im quite new to Python.

Below Code works fine for a single given url

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl="https//www.xxxxxxxxx.com"

r=requests.get(baseurl)

c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"biz-us"})

for br in soup.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")
```

This is my tried code for accessing urls from CSV

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("input.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        url = row[0]

    r=requests.get(url)

    c=r.content

    soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

    all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"biz-country-us"})

    for br in soup.find_all("br"):
        br.replace_with("\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your `csv` file with the urls. What have you tried so far to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you CKE. I have put my new version of the code where I tried to access the urls from CSV. Please check. for CSV, we can parse any urls. Say something like yahoo news article

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to use your loop properly and also get the array of urls. Try this out

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df1 = pandas.read_csv("input.csv", skiprows=0)  #assuming headers are in first row

urls = df1['url_column_name'].tolist()   #get the urls in an array list

i=0
for i in range(len(urls)):
    r=requests.get(urls[i])
    c=r.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

    all=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"biz-country-us"})

    for br in soup.find_all("br"):
        br.replace_with("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a csv file named `linklists.csv` and within this there is a header `Links`. Now you can use all the links available under the header `Links` following the method I've shown below:

```
import csv
import requests

with open("linklists.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for link in reader:
        res = requests.get(link['Links'])
        print(res.url)
```